# Call C++ DLL in Delphi app

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I want to call a function of a C++ DLL in my Delphi app.
The problem is that i get an access violation. But not while calling my C++ DLL but when I leave the Delphi function in which I do that.

Error message (shortened):
**Access violation at 0x7445c9f1: Reading from address 0x00000000.**

My C++ method is like that:

```
extern "C" __stdcall void SetName(LPCTSTR name) {strcpy_s(nameInDll,512,name);};
```

My Delphi call looks like this:

```
begin   
   ...
   hDll := LoadLibrary('myCpp.dll');
   SetName := getprocaddress(hDll, 'SetName');
   SetName(pchar(myControl.text));  //  <--- exception NOT here
   ...
end;  // <--- exception here
```

the funny thing is that it works if I use hard coded text as input for the DLL call like this:

```
SetName(pchar('myName'));
```

***EDIT:***
I missed the **__stdcall** definition in my C++ DLL. It was defined in an macro. I corrected the C++ method definition above.

After seeing that and your tips I came up with an solution that works:

```
procedure SetName(s: PChar); stdcall; external 'myCpp.dll';

begin   
   ...
   SetName(pchar(myControl.text));
   ...
end;
```

Comment: Try [this similiar thread][1], hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244441/accessviolation-when-using-c-dll-from-delphi

Comment: You need to show the declaration of `SetName`. I bet you have not declared a calling convention, or have declared the wrong calling convention. Your C++ method is most likely using `cdecl`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like `SetName` uses the wrong calling convention, try using `cdecl;`

Something like this:

```
var
  SetName : procedure(nameArg: PChar); cdecl;
```

Otherwise your stack will be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Is the DLL compiled for Ansi or Unicode?  `LPCTSTR` maps to `wchar_t*` when `UNICODE` is defined, or to `char*` otherwise.  That affects how you use the DLL in Delphi, where `wchar_t*` is equivilent to `PWideChar` and `char*` is equivilent to `PAnsiChar` In Delphi.

Answer (score -1):

depending on heavy your work is, in compiler options you may need to set:

```
minimum enum size:  double word
record field alignment:  quad word
```

Comment: neither of these settings have any bearing on this question. Ther are no enums and no records.